# Expand Matlab figures "from up to down"

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, figure, figures

I'm working on a resizable GUI in MATLAB, and, since the coordinates are "upside down", if I want to resize a figure keeping the **top** border in place and making the **bottom** border move down, I'm having to recalculate the OuterPosition property and apply, which causes an annoying blinking effect.

Is there some way to use the underlying java objects to accomplish this effect without the blinking?